# Run sdbinst.exe and / or DISM upon MSIX install

Tags: installation, windows-installer, msix

for those experienced in authoring MSIX packages outside Visual Studio.

Case: My client (game publisher) has a title that needs to go on MS Store. No code is available, only the binary.
The binary , aside the files + registries needs a sdb shim being installed (for setting up the backwards compatibility with earlier MS OSes) via sdbinst.exe and also to enable DirectDraw via DISM.

Innosetup (my installer of choice so far) has a dedicated section where i can do the said CLI execution upon installation but i can't find anything of sorts for MSIX.

Should you need extra details, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your insights.
Best regards
n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike MSI-based or script based installer the MSIX package is very limited when it comes to executing custom code during the installation.

Recently Microsoft introduced the possibility of running a PowerShell script when your application launches/exits. Maybe you can use this as a workaround, but [as I said here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix-deployment/app-manifest-using-custominstall/m-p/1503750/highlight/true#M537), I don't know if they accept such kind of packages in the store.

Another cleaner option is to create your own EXE wrapper that handles all this when launched and at the end launches your main app. Then in your MSIX package, configure this launcher as an entry point (shortcut target) instead of your app exe.

Comment: as i was afraid.. Anyway thanks for your answer Bogdan, your suggestion with the launcher may actually be the solution.